# Position textview in a scrollview exactly one screen down

Tags: android, android-layout

The title might be slightly confusing, so please suggest a better one. What I'm trying to achieve is to have two *pages* in a `scrollview`. And a `textview`  at the top of the second *page*.

I tried doing this using XML by making a dummy view at the bottom of the screen and positioning the `textview` below it.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignparentbottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/screenbottom" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Heading"
    android:layout_below="@+id/screenbottom"
    android:marginTop="0dp"
    ...
/>
```

But this did not work as the textview somehow jumped to the top of the screen.

I was able to workaround this in my Java code by finding the screenheight using `DisplayMetrics`.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
TextView resultstv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultstv);
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)resultstv.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0, metrics.heightPixels, 0, 0);
```

I wanted to know why my method using only XML didn't work and if there's a better way to do it using XML.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A LinearLayout will solve this.

Comment: How so? And why does RelativeLayout fail?